# C# If Button IsEnabled, its triggering event on click

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have next issue, I am working on small c#-wpf application,
and on load I am disabling button which is ussualy used to do some action on click, and it looks like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Password))
    {
        btnActivate.IsEnabled=false;
    }
}
```

and somewhere I am checking my password field, for example:

```
private void password_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        if (password.Password == "drag0n")
        {
            btnActivate.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnActivate.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And my problem is next, when user enter `"drag0n"` and press enter, button should be just enabled, but its not only enabled, its calling automatic his event `_Click`, I don't know why does that happening, because in that case, if my button is just enabled event `_Click` is also called, and if user clicks on that button, event is called again, so actually my event `onclick` is called twice.

My question is how can I stop calling my Click event if I set `IsEnabled=true`. When I set `IsEnabled=true` I just want it to be enabled for pressing and I don't want execute event `_Click`.
I want to execute event `_Click` only when my button is pressed as it should work and not on `IsEnabled=true`.

Thanks guys,
Cheers

Comment: Is the button marked as default? If so, maybe the Click event is being fired automatically because of the pressed Enter. Try setting the `IsDefault` property of the button to false. Or if you don't want to, you can set the `e.Handled` to true when you set the button to enabled, that will stop the KeyEvent from bubbling onward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click event occurs when you press Enter key, because this button is the default control in a form.

If you don't want click event on Enter key, you should either make this button not default or not process Enter key pressing in your  button click (`e.Handled = true` -> when Enter is pressed).

Or try to change your code:

```
private void password_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
    {
        if (password.Password == "drag0n")
        {
            e.Handled = true; // add this line
            btnActivate.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnActivate.IsEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did exacly like that, and problem is solved! Thanks guys!